# use of includes or left outer joins for complex nested associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, left-join

I have four models

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :share_types
  belongs_to :user
end
class ShareType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :shares
  belongs_to :company
end
class Share < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :share_type
end
class User < ActiveRecord:Base
 has_many :companies
 has_many :shares
end
```

Now list of all companies where company is owned by current_user or user have shares in a company something like this.

```
Company.joins(share_types:[:shares]).where("shares.user_id=? OR companies.user_id=?", @user.id, @user.id)
```

but with left outer join another I do not know how to use includes with or conditions another hint is

```
Company.includes(share_types:[:shares]).where(shares:{user_id: @user.id} OR companies:{user_id: 1})
```

How can I do that.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get my expected result with the help of references. Here is my query just posting to help others.

```
Company.includes(share_types:[:shares]).where("shares.user_id=? OR companies.user_id=?", 1,1).references(:shares)
```

its working thanks to The Rails 4 Way by Obie Fernandez